# Android Studio - Virtualization

Tags: android, android-studio

In the BIOS (GigaByte - GA-AM1M-S2H (1.1) Version F2 - Athlon 5150 APU with Radeon R3)I have the option SVM Mode is Enabled, Android Studio show the message: "Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)".
I use Windows 7 64bits

any idea?
Thank

Comment: Only Intel processors supports VT-x

Comment: does android studio work when SVM mode is disabled? I use android studio in Ubuntu. The performance is excellent with 4gb ram even emulator without any lag.